# how to hide view in sencha extjs

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, hide

I want to hide a view in sencha ext js. I tried  hide() but not working. Here is my view configed:

```
Ext.define('MobileUnity.view.popup.SettingMenuPop', {

    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'settingmenupop',
    requires: [
        'Ext.Panel'
    ],

    config: {

        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        modal: true,
        hideOnMaskTap: true,
        hidden: true,
        cls: 'settingPopPosition',
        showAnimation: {type:'slide',direction:'left'},
        hideAnimation: {type:'slideOut',direction:'right'}
})
```

I use it for pop up view, but I dont know how to hide it in my controller. 
Any ideas regarding to this matter.

Comment: `hide` should work. Could you please make a minimal verifyable example in Sencha fiddle?

Comment: Paste your code. How are you using hide

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.lookupReference('reference of your view').hide()` or `this.getView().close()` or `this.getView().destroy()` or `this.getView().remove()`